# Unable to run service fabric actors application

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have installed latest service fabric 2.3.311 runtime and when I run actor application. I see the error attached. Please help!. I'm stuck here.But I'm able to run all the stateless and state ful services.

[image]

Comment: this seems to be working in 2.301 runtime and not on the latest/

Comment: Check inner exceptions for details. Most probably some assembly cannot be found, so you'd need to recheck your references and/or redirect assembly versions.

Comment: Do you use Nuget packages with a *.3.311 version? Did you try re-installing the dev cluster? Does it work when using an Azure cluster? (like a party cluster).

Comment: Can you post a stack trace and any inner exceptions?